# KQL Query to create alert for Azure Storage accounts

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, kql, azure-monitoring

I am trying to create alerts for storage accounts using KQL Queries, I need to create alert when some one changes on storage account networking, also when blob lifecycle changes from HOT to COOl or ARCHIVE

below is the query i am trying with

```
 AzureActivity
 | where ResourceProviderValue contains "MICROSOFT.STORAGE" and CategoryValue contains 
  "Administrative"
 | where Properties has  "NETWORKS"
```

but unable to forward from here.  any leads is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the below Results:**

You can use the below KQL to create an alert rule if some one changes on storage account networking.

**Query**

```
AzureActivity
| where ResourceProviderValue contains "Microsoft.storage" and CategoryValue contains "Administrative"
| where Properties has  "networkAcls"
| project ResourceProviderValue,CategoryValue,Properties
```

**Output:**

[image]

Next, You can create action groups with either a new action group or an existing one used to send notifications through mail or sms.

Here is my snippet at the last of creating an alert rule.

[image]

After creation, you can check the alerts in the monitor or through the mail if someone made changes to your Networking.

I made changes in networking by adding an address range in the portal.

**Portal:**

[image]

**Email:**
I got an alert both through the mail and in the alert section.

[image]

[image]

The same process you can use the below query to create alert rule  when the blob lifecycle changes from HOT to COOl or ARCHIVE.

**Query:**

```
 AzureActivity
    | where ResourceProviderValue contains "Microsoft.storage" and CategoryValue contains "Administrative"
    | where OperationNameValue == "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/blobs/changeLifecycle"
    | where properties contains "NewTier\": \"Cool\"" or Properties contains "NewTier\": \"Archive\""
    | project ResourceProviderValue,CategoryValue,Properties,OperationNameValue.
```

Comment: Thanks Venkatesan,  i am able to do it now.  also i am looking for query for alert when storage account used capacity exceeds 80%.  can you please help in finding it. thanks

Comment: Can u Post this as a new query, with more details so that I can try ?

Comment: AzureMetrics
|   where ResourceProvider  == "MICROSOFT.STORAGE"
|   where MetricName        == "UsedCapacity".       This query just list out  the used capacity but need to improve to include if used capacity exceeds 80% then trigger alert